# Issue with float labels

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

I'm trying to implement [floatlabels](http://clubdesign.github.io/floatlabels.js/) but for some reason I can't get it working.

Here is what I’ve done:

First I call the JS file

```
<script src="js/floatlabels.min.js"></script>
```

then the script

```
  <script>
    $('input.floatlabel').floatlabel();
</script>
```

then the label

```
<input type="text" id="test-input" placeholder="This is the placeholder" class="floatlabel">
```

…. but nothing happens…. Any thoughts why? I believe I followed the instructions...

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you need to wait for everything to load first:

```
$(function() {
    $('input.floatlabel').floatlabel();
});
```

because if you run that command in the console, it binds properly and works.

Answer (score 2):

It works just added in `$(document).ready`:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('input.floatlabel').floatlabel();
    });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BxKLF/4/)

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
   $('input.floatlabel').floatlabel();
</script>
```

That should be

this

```
<script>
  $(function(){ // document.ready
    $('input.floatlabel').floatlabel();
  });
</script>
```

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/